# Creating multiple accounts under one email address

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'd like to play Minecraft with my 8-year old son on the LAN, but doing so requires a different account.  I don't mind paying for another account, but adding another one seems to require a different email address, and I'd like to use the same email address.   How can I add another account with the same email address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mojang accounts are bound to e-mails and not usernames, you need another mail. You can create a mail in a few minutes.

[You can sign up for Hotmail here.](https://signup.live.com/)
[You can sign up for Gmail here.](https://mail.google.com/mail/signup)

Or, if your mail provider supports it (confirmed working on Hotmail and Gmail (thanks mrlemon for gmail)), you can add a + and a tag to your email address and it'll still arrive (for example, ardaozkal@outlook.com to ardaozkal+minecraft2@outlook.com etc, you can change minecraft2 to anything you want)

[image: login page showing that this is allowed]

Comment: Tip: you can use the +tag thing on most websites. They don't need to specifically allow it, the mail will still arrive.

Comment: Can confirm this works for gmail as well. And congratulations on 2000 reputation.

Comment: Gmail will automatically tag received emails with `+string`