# How can I play Minecraft with my son without him having an email address?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Other questions I found that are similar but didn't answer my question:

- [How do I make a second minecraft account for my son?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/288501/222105)
- [How to play minecraft against my son with 2 PCs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/363483/222105)

I want to play Minecraft locally with my son (from two computers), but (a) he doesn't have an email address, (b) I don't want to set up an email account for him (and he's too young for that to be legal in the U.S. anyway).  I am fine on paying for two copies of Minecraft but I want to make sure I get it set up right.

I explored the Minecraft site but didn't find an answer to this question.

Can I just install Minecraft on both computers using one single account?  Or what should I do in order to play with him without setting up a second email?

---

I do have more than one email address of my own, but my secondary concern is, when he gets old enough to have/want his own email, I'd like him to be able to retain whatever account access he has (e.g. any worlds he's built) and not have it be dependent on me.  So, secondary question: is there any way to ensure he'll have this access in the future, apart from setting up an email address for him now?

Comment: Are you adverse to setting up a second email account for yourself?

Comment: @BenM I guess the implication is that it's definitely impossible to get a second Minecraft account without a second email account?  Do you know if it's possible/easy to "edit" email address later (e.g. when he eventually gets his own)?

Comment: @Wildcard you can change email password easily/personal details, but you will not be able to change the email address.

Comment: I don't know for certain if it's impossible, but browsing the related questions suggests to me that each Minecraft account definitely needs a separate address (although, depending on your email provider, it may be possible to use the '+' trick  -- see https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245467/creating-multiple-accounts-under-one-email-address?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, right now you could create an email address of what your son wants and fill in your personal details, and buy minecraft. When your son grows up, change the personal details to that of your son. So, your son will get that email address and will not lose the worlds when he grows up. This is an easy way, and see [this](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27442?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) if you have gmail, but I am pretty sure this can be done using other email providers.

I hope this helped, if not then sorry. Have fun playing with your son. :D